# facebook connect javascript example available?

Tags: javascript, facebook

1. in order to try out facebook connect, is it ok, if my registered status look like below

```
Directory Status: Not submitted
Directory Status: Not submitted
API Key
    ...
Application Secret
    ...
Application ID
    ...
Contact Email
    user@yahoo.com
Support Email Address
    user@yahoo.com
Connect URL
    http://localhost:8888/testapp
Base Domain

FBML/iframe
    iframe
Developer Mode
    On
Application Type
    Website
Private Install
    No
Application Description
    TestLogin
```

2. any simple html demo on using faceebook connect to do authentication using javascript?

Comment: Now that you've published your secret key, make sure you change it (or if that's not possible, delete your app on FB and create a new one) before you let anyone else use the app.

Comment: Also - please set @Dennis' answer as the chosen one as its help both you and I. I too was looking for a more concise answer and his link helped.